# WSO2 ESB - Java 7 Watch Service

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

As I'm pretty new to wso2 esb, sorry if my question is stupid.

I'm having the requirement to listen on file system events (polling is not allowed by architecture team...). As soon as a file arrives, a ESB flow is triggered and will pick up the message. I've already done this in the past using Java 7 watch Service on an different ESB product. I've stepped through the documentation (Custom connector, mediator etc..) but haven't found (or missed )the helpfull information.

Can anybody give me a hint how this could be achived in wso2 esb?

Thanks
Martin

Answer (score 0):

Try [VFS](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/VFS+Transport)(Virtual file system transport) transport. It will pick files in a configured time period..Samples are listed [here](https://docs.wso2.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=33136056)

Comment: Unfortunately the VFS does polling in the configured time period( which is not allowed by the architecture team). The Watch Service registers for operating system events, and will get a notification from the OS when something changed (file created, modified etc.). So I could use VFS if it would be allowed, but unfortunately it isn't and that's why I'd like to use the watch service